# Can I use differential I/O pins of FPGA as high speed comparator?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, comparator, differential, voltage-reference

High speed comparators are rather expensive and speed is what FPGAs are very good at. On the other hand, FPGAs (in my case: XC3S400) have paired differential pins in each bank  that their voltages are compared ( At least I think so !). They also have *Vref* for single ended standards that may act as a comparator.

I want to know if I can use those ***differential I/O pair pins*** as a comparator -and if so- how should I do that ( Should I connect a vref and use single ended standards or simply connect two voltages to differential I/O pins ?)

***EDITION:*** I tried it and works excellent !!!

Comment: If you stay within the documented voltage limits it ought to work after a fashion - precision may be more like 50-100mv than 1mv. How precise do you need?

Comment: @BrianDrummond precision is not a big concern, just converting a sine wave to logic level square wave.

Comment: @Aug, that is how all the ADCs in the world work!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you can. There are some applications notes using the differential pairs inside an FPGA as a low cost ADC.

There is a very good document describing this that you can use for your design:

[Analysis on Digital Implementation of Sigma-Delta ADC with
Passive Analog Components](http://www.uob.edu.bh/uob__files/651/V2-N2-03.pdf)

Comment: the link does not work for me, do you have an alternative?

Comment: [Analysis on Digital Implementation of Sigma-Delta ADC with Passive Analog Components](http://www.uob.edu.bh/uob__files/651/V2-N2-03.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your guidance!  I tried it and works nice. Now I have a very high speed comparator at no more cost !

Comment: Glad it worked, I used it long time ago and was surprised how easy it was to implement a simple ADC inside the FPGA without any active components. I saved a lot of time and money doing so :)

Comment: I found the linked paper a bit hard to read. This ["adc in an fpga" blogpost](https://davidkessner.wordpress.com/2011/05/01/adc-in-an-fpga) is much more accessible, IMO.

Comment: please NOTE: the S-D LVDT ADC has some heavy patents attached. Sure using it for hobbyist... but if anyone is thinking of putting it into a product ...

Comment: That is total BS Jon, I have been using it for over a decade. Just becasue a smart ass decided to patent it does not mean it is their design, I can show you at least 3 industrial application on the market for the past 10 years or so that uses this simple ADC idea.